# UNCalendarNotificationTrigger Hourly Trigger returns wrong trigger date

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10

I'm using the following to get a local notification triggered every hour.

```
let reminderTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: dateStart), repeats: true)
let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "reminder", content: reminderContent, trigger: reminderTrigger)
```

This is based on Apple's documentation here - https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger

However, when I print the next trigger date, it is completely wrong.

```
print(dateStart)
print(reminderTrigger.nextTriggerDate())
```

This is the output -

```
2016-09-10 05:18:58 +0000
Optional(2016-09-11 04:00:06 +0000)
```

However, it should be

```
2016-09-10 06:00:00 +0000
```

I've tried the Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Yearly in a similar way and all of them return correct next trigger dates. The hourly is the only one that seems incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, the only difference being that the only offset is incorrect, even when setting the `timeZone` on the date components object. When the date arrives, the notification isn't triggered, but it also isn't listed in pending or delivered notifications.

Comment: You definitely have an issue with your TimeZone/Calendar settings. If you don't specify the hour, it is automatically set to a default value, hence that works regardless of your device settings.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem like you.

```
        UNNotificationRequest *request = notifyDict[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", indexPath.row]];
        UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = (UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *)request.trigger;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
        NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:trigger.nextTriggerDate];
```

I get the trigger's nextTriggerDate, but the date is not the value i set for the trigger before.